# Probability to pick a certain amount of balls of some color

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose there are 100 balls in a box. 20 balls are blue, 30 balls are green and 50 balls are yellow. Now we randomly pick out 10 balls out of the box (one ball after the other) and we don't put the balls back in the box.

What's the probability of picking exactly 2 blue balls, 3 green balls and 5 yellow balls?

My wrong attempt of a solution is

$(\frac{20}{100} *  \frac{19}{99}) + (\frac{30}{98 }* \frac{29}{97 }* \frac{28}{96}) + (\frac{50}{95 }* \frac{49}{94 }* \frac{48}{93 }* \frac{47}{92 }* \frac{46}{91})$

the correct solution seems to be

$(\frac{20}{100} *  \frac{19}{99}) * (\frac{30}{98 }* \frac{29}{97 }* \frac{28}{96}) * (\frac{50}{95 }* \frac{49}{94 }* \frac{48}{93 }* \frac{47}{92 }* \frac{46}{91})  *(\frac{10!}{2!3!5!})$

Thanks for your help fellas!

Comment: The plus signs has to be replaced by multiplication signs. Then this expression has to be multiplied by $\frac{10!}{2!\cdot 3! \cdot 5!}$

Comment: Yes your solution is correct now.

Comment: Sehr gerne, mein Freund.

Comment: Der Term stimmt und das Ergebnis auch.

Answer (score 2):

Total number of balls = 20 + 30 +50.
Choose 2 out of 20, 3 out of 30 and 5 out of 50. Divide by the total number of balls in the box choose total number of balls picked -> 2+3+5 = 10

$$
\frac{\binom{20}{2}  \binom{30}{3}  \binom{50}{5} }{\binom{100}{10}} = 0.094418
$$

Answer (score -1):

The product you have is the probability that you will draw, in this order, blue, blue, green, green, green, yellow, yellow, yellow, yellow, yellow.  Changing the order of the colors does not change that probability that you draw that sequence, so you should multiply this probability by the number of possible sequences.

$3!$ is the number of ways of arranging blue, green, and yellow, but there is more than one of each type in this case.

Comment: You haven´t mentioned that the plus signs were wrong.